# MATLAB - Create Array Variable in For Loop and Plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I will preface this post with the obvious fact that I'm not very experienced in MATLAB and this post may be somewhat confusing. Any help is appreciated!

I need to store data inside two parameters but unsure on how to do it. The number of "x" values is known but it is a user inputted value, so it's not something that can be hard coded. Same as the "y" values. Here's a simplified example of what I think I need (numbers are hard coded here for the sake of the example).

Then, the final figure should have multiple plots on it. Each "x" variable is its own "output" that needs to be plotted. In the end I need "x" number of plots with "z" and "y" being the (X,Y) coordinates for each "x" plot, respectively.

EDIT: Updated example code.

```
list = [.0025, .005, .0075];
x = input('How many? ');
y = linspace(2.4*10^9, 5.0*10^9, 1000);

z = zeros(x, length(y));

for i = x
    time = list(i)/(3*10^8);
    for j = y
        z(i,j) = (time * j);
    end
end

for i = x
    plot(z(i,j));
end
```

I get the following error:

```
Requested 3x2400000000 (53.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference. Creation of arrays greater
than this limit may take a long time and cause MATLAB to become unresponsive. See array size limit or
preference panel for more information.
```

The example that I provided could be totally wrong but I hope I have explained enough for someone to provide feedback.

Comment: When you pass `plot` a matrix, it plots each column independently. Maybe that's what you need (your question is not really clear)

Comment: I updated my example code, hopefully it's more clear for what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

Create the z-Array beforehand to your needs: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html

Then you can fill it with `z[x,y] = x+y`

HTH

Comment: I did that already but I get this error. "Requested 3x2400000000 (53.6GB) array exceeds maximum array size preference." But the "x" is 5 and the "y" is 1000.

Comment: I could imagine theres a problem with parsing th _y_ variable. Could you paste your whole code?

Comment: Could you just for testing purposes try: z = zeros(x, 1000); ...apparently the linspace() cmd creates this humongous array which is actually kinda weird. Just want to make shure the error is somewhere in the linspace cmd or not. (dont have my laptop with matlab with me - would do it myself then)